# Chrome Extension Active Tab Selecting Problem

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

A short time, looking at the issue of Chrome Extension Development.

I use jQuery and plugins. But not selecting DOM elements with jQuery.

example code here; (background.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function alertValue() {
    var a = $("#divName").val();
        alert(a);
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(alertValue); 
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

As a result, returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to read a value of some element on a current page when a user clicks a browser action icon.

To do this you need to use a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html) to actualy read the value on a page, and [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html) to communicate between a background page and a content script.

Comment: I agree, OP needs to explain better. As well as the links @serg has provided, I'd recommend looking at the [architectre overview](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html#arch) and make sure you understand how it all fits together as I'm not sure you do yet.